# Segmentation fault error while checking whether it is a binary search tree or not

Tags: python, linux, algorithm

I try to submit a code problem but the grader doesn't accept my result. I can't see the test case, I see only the error message that states unknown `signal 11 (Time used: 0.81/10.00, memory used: 101203968/536870912.)`

I know that in signal #11 in Linux stands for a segmentation fault. But I can't get what's wrong with my code. Other test cases are run without any problems. So I think that it is mostly a design problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys, threading

sys.setrecursionlimit(10**7) # max depth of recursion
threading.stack_size(2**25)  # new thread will get stack of such size

def IsBinarySearchTree(tree):
  # Implement correct algorithm here
  min = -sys.maxsize
  max = sys.maxsize

  def is_bst_until(idx_node,maxi,mini):
    if idx_node == -1:
      return True

    node = tree[idx_node]
    key = node[0]
    idx_left = node[1]
    idx_right = node[2]

    #print('max',maxi, "min", mini)

    if (key>maxi) or (key<mini):
      #print("False", key, maxi,mini)
      return False

    return (is_bst_until(idx_right, maxi, key+1)) and (is_bst_until(idx_left, key-1, mini))

  #print(tree)
  if len(tree) == 0:
      return True
  return is_bst_until(0, max, min)


def main():
  nodes = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
  tree = []
  for i in range(nodes):
    tree.append(list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())))
  if IsBinarySearchTree(tree):
    print("CORRECT")
  else:
    print("INCORRECT")
```

threading.Thread(target=main).start()
Input: The first line contains the number of vertices . The vertices of the tree are numbered from 0 to −1. Vertex 0 is the root. The next  lines contain information about vertices 0, 1, ...,  − 1 in order. Each of these lines contains three integers ,  and h —  is the key of the -th vertex,  is the index of the left child of the -th vertex, and h is the index of the right child of the -th vertex. If  doesn’t have left or right child (or both), the corresponding  or h (or both) will be equal to −1.

Output: If the given binary tree is a correct binary search tree (see the definition in the problem description), output one word “CORRECT” (without quotes). Otherwise, output one-word “INCOR- RECT” (without quotes).

```
Examples:

3
1 1 2
2 -1 -1
3 -1 -1
INCORRECT

3
2 1 2
1 -1 -1
3 -1 -1
CORRECT
```

The problem might indicate the stack depth is a potential issue, and thus recursion is not a viable strategy to handle large cases.

But I'm not sure. I'll appreciate hearing your opinions towards this problem before refactoring the code.

Comment: @jdehesa No, there were not any restriction about recursion. I'm not 100% that the problem in recursion

Comment: Oh sorry I misread that, I thought you said the statement of the problem indicated that using recursion would cause issues.

Comment: @jdehesa yep, any ideas then?

Comment: Just increased threading.stack_size(2**25) to threading.stack_size(2**27) and passed the grader.